# Expected number of cards needed to draw from 52 card deck to get a pair

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a standard 52 card deck, what is the expected number of cards needed to draw until we have two cards with the same number?

It's not hard to do for a fixed value (say fix Kings, then deck order can be _K__K__K__K__, all other cards have 1/5 probability of being in each space, so we expect 48*2/5 + 2 = 21.2 cards to be drawn before we find 2 Kings). Is the solution similar when the value is not fixed?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721821/mathematical-expectation-of-picking-cards-of-the-same-value-from-a-standard-52-c?rq=1

Comment: thank you! did not see this